# How do I deal with many zero values in terms of correlation?

Tags: r, correlation, error, zero-inflation

I am currently working on my master thesis. I have determined a simulation model for tax returns and to verify this I would like to use true values.

I would like to determine the correlation between my simulated and true values. However, the problem is that I have simulated zero values for some years and the true values are >0. Can I determine the correlation in R by means of "cor.test"? In general, what is the most useful way to show the correlation between my simulated and true values?

[image]

Comment: That was just a snippet so far. How about my updated image?

Comment: Looks better, you can try cor.test, but I would use method="spearman" or "kendall" instead of pearson correlation.

Comment: Spearman's rank correlation is 0.447. Kendall, on the other hand, has 0.3320096. My question would now be: are the zero values ​​taken into account in both cases? Is the determination of the correlation statistically correct in this way? Thank you again for the quick help!

Comment: You don't need any performance measure to tell that the model is terrible. It completely fails in about one third of the cases and at best performes somewhat decently for the rest. For tax returns this is not a model I would find useful.

Comment: I suspect most experienced people will agree with @Roland. But the wider context is this: 1. The OP is at Master's level and is likely to be challenged or given a poor grade if they made such an assertion without adding extra substance. 2. Other goals might well include saying quite how far this model is deficient or how it compares with others. A kind of Harumph! saying "It is clearly useless" is one I agree with but  more can be said.

Comment: Quantifying the performance of models is a generally good thing to do. I don't think it is helpful to scoff at this when the question is getting at something that is important and non-obvious.

Comment: Note that the graph here has to be examined carefully and could all too easily be misread, even though one should always look at the axis labels. The answer of @mkt shows better practices on scales and including a reference line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zero is a value like any other value to each kind of correlation. Each correlation takes zeros into account in its way:

- as implying a deviation from the mean of either variable in the case of Pearson correlation
- as ranked suitably in the case of Spearman correlation or Kendall correlation.

One commenter suggested a preference for rank correlation without giving a reason.

I'd back up here and ask why you think correlation is interesting or useful. Pearson correlation is best thought of as measuring how far the data follow a linear relationship and rank correlation as measuring how far the data follow a monotonic relationship. A presence or even abundance of zeros may or may not be consistent with either idea.

It's possible that you seek to use correlation as a measurement of agreement, but neither measure works well for that purpose. Consider that the correlation (any version) between $x$ and $bx$ for $b \gg 0$ is identical to $1$ but such $x$ and $bx$ are very different. The point is strengthened by noting that any $a$ added so that $y = a + bx$ does not affect any correlation.

If you want a single measurement of agreement, concordance correlation may help;  but it is more likely that you should be looking at the entire pattern of differences, observed MINUS simulated. And, last but certainly not least, a plot is indispensable here.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Many responses now mentioned the RSME. Why I have now also understood. In fact, I wanted to show the quality of the simulation. RSME could be easily calculated in R: 

library(Metrics)
rmse(data$actual, data$predicted)

R^2 would also be a good quality criterion, right? Would it be appropriate to run a simple OLS regression here? I'm usually a tax law person, so this is all relatively new to me.

Comment: I don't object to RMSE or MAE (mentioned so far by one person @mkt) but my point remains that looking at the differences directly is the starting point. RMSE calculated from error = observed MINUS simulated  rather overlooks which errors are positive or negative. No; $R^2$ is here just correlation squared and just as bad an idea as correlation, or certainly no better. A regression would at least indicate something about tilt and bias, but will help only to the extent that the overall relationship is linear.

Comment: I will continue to work with this for now. So the goal would be to find a regression that most closely describes the numbers, correct? As this was my first post in this forum: Should I post here again if I have further questions or create a new question?

Comment: I am not strongly supportive of regression unless it works well. You can edit your question if you change it or ask a new question if that is unrelated.

Comment: You should investigate the cases that is predicted as zero or nearly so, and try to understand why. That might give hints for a better model.

Answer (score 10):

Because you are comparing simulated vs. true values, a correlation between the two is not the best way to evaluate the quality of your simulations.

This is easy to illustrate: imagine your model is predicting temperature across a bunch of cities but you accidentally messed up your code and it has added 1000 degrees to every temperature prediction. Adding this 1000 (or 1 million, or any number) does not affect the correlation! You can get a *perfect* correlation between these crazy simulated temperatures and the true temperatures even though they are terrible predictions. In other words, correlation ignores the *offset* or *bias* in the predictions.

Here's a simple visualisation of this type of situation:

[image: Strong correlation or R-squared with terrible predictions]

Instead, a better solution is to compare the true and simulated values using a metric such as Root Mean Square Error (RMSE) or Mean Absolute Error (MAE). These calculate the quantitative error and in the earlier example would tell you that the predictions are off by 1000 degrees.

Your plot is informative: it clearly shows the peculiar feature of the model prediction error that you mention, which is that the model is predicting zero across a wide range of true positive values. I would therefore show it alongside any such error metric calculation, ideally with a (partly transparent) 1:1 line to highlight how far each prediction is from the true value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will try to realise your idea regarding the illustration.

Comment: The plot here matches what would be good practice for the OP, namely equal scales on the axes and a line of equality as reference.